# Why Will Protractor Webdriver Update Not Execute?

Tags: angularjs, angular, selenium, protractor

I am trying to use Protractor on a baseline run of the Angular Quickstart Seed.

However, when I run Protractor, or simply try to update the webdriver myself I get the following output:

```
[11:31:24] I/file_manager - creating folder C:\Users\davidtaylorjr\devbox\home\angula
r2-fundamentals\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
events.js:161
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1085:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:186:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:603:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:433:38)
```

I have not modified any of the files and they are the files that are available in the [Angular Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

Comment: Can you give us more details on your environment? What OS (i'm assuming windows because of the paths, but what version) are you using? What version of Node? I'm not able to replicate this with node `v6.9.2` on OSX. Are you behind a proxy? What happens when you run `./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: Windows 10 latest update, no proxy. Node 7.7.0 

How do I run that?  If it is just `npm run ./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update` then the output gives an error about missing a script. @NickTomlin

Comment: However you would normally run an executable from the windows command line. You'll have to figure out the exact pathing for windows but it should be something like `node_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update`

Comment: @NickTomlin it gives an E/Downloader error when it reaches the Gecko driver. Unable to verify leaf signature

Comment: Unfortunately this is seems like a networking issue between your machine and the driver endpoints. I don't have time to boot up a windows machine to verify this but that's typically the cause here. There's an ugly workaround where you can `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` before `ode_modules\.bin\webdriver-manager update` that may ignore this but there's something deeper going on that you'll need to figure out

Comment: @NickTomlin that actually worked. Not sure what would be causing the issue but that did allow the update to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software is having a conflict with current network settings and SSL Certificate Verification.

Protractor and Web-Driver have a way to deal with this by setting a flag on your update command. The command set should be as follows:

`webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`

This will allow you to update without being flagged with SSL errors.

This should only be used if other methods of working with SSL fails.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver-manager on `update` downloads some drivers/jars from the below sources. Looks like there is some issue during this. Can you manually download and verify if you are able to access the below url's

Sources: from [webdriver-manager configs](https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/blob/master/config.json)

```
  "cdnUrls": {
    "selenium": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "chromedriver": "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "geckodriver": "https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/",
    "iedriver": "https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/",
    "androidsdk": "http://dl.google.com/android/"
  }
```

Comment: The googleapis links all take me to XML files, the Geckodriver link does not exist on github it gives a 404 error. And Android SDK's link doesn't exist.

Comment: These are the base Url's and webdriver-manager appends the correct versions and other watever info and triggers the download. What I suggested was you to manually may be curl or any other check if you are seeing any certificate errors from wherever location you are running the `webdriver-manager` - whether a docker container or Vagrant machine